# Elasticsearch Query String Query returns all documents

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, lucene

I have an indice named users

When I make a request on `http://localhost:9200/users/_search?pretty=true` with the following query:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/users/_search?pretty=true" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
    "query" : "firstName: Daulet"
}
}
}'
```

the query returns two users with the following names:

`firstName: Daulet`

`firstName: Daulet Nurlanuly`

How do I make the query string query return a the document with `firstName: Daulet` ?

I've looked up that Elasticsearch uses Apache Lucene's request syntax and that for the strict search I would need to do the following by enclosing request in quotes as followes:

`firstName: "Daulet"`

But it is already enclosed within quotes

How do I do that using only Query String Query?

** UPDATE **

The response I get when I make a GET request at http://localhost:9200/users:

```
{
    "users": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "userentity": {
                "properties": {
                    "firstName": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "language": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "lastName": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "refresh_interval": "1s",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "provided_name": "users",
                "creation_date": "1530245236170",
                "store": {
                    "type": "fs"
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "IlE1Ynv2Q462LBttptVaTg",
                "version": {
                    "created": "5060999"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that you need to surround the value with double quotes. You're on the right path and you simply need to escape the double quotes and use the `firstName.keyword` field instead of `firstName`, basically like this:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/users/_search?pretty=true" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
    "query" : "firstName.keyword:\"Daulet\""
}
}
}'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it works only if I search for  " firstname: \"Daulet Nurlanuly\" " . If I try   " firstname: \"Daulet\" "  it returns both again. And surprisingly it works for " firstname: \"Nurlanuly\" "  as it returns the user Daulet Nurlanuly

Comment: Ok, that's because `firstName` is analyzed. Can you update your question with the result you get from `curl -XGET localhost:9200/users` ?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'm sorry, but even now that I am searching for the solution that you've given I hardly can find it in the docs of Elasticsearch. Where can I read more about it?